# Listeners for dynamically created items

Tags: android, android-widget, remoteview

I've home scrren widget, and I'm generating some items inside (i have a layout of this item) the widget and setting some listeners on them. It's very simple, just like this:

```
RemoteViews currentItem1 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.complex_list_item);
    updateViews.addView(R.id.panelNews, currentItem1);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, ForexWidget.class);
    intent1.setAction(Constants.ACTION_PRESSED_ITEM);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent1, 0);
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.singleLine, pendingIntent1);

    RemoteViews currentItem2 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.complex_list_item);
    updateViews.addView(R.id.panelNews, currentItem2);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, ForexWidget.class);
    intent2.setAction(Constants.ACTION_PRESSED_ITEM);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent2, 0);
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.singleLine, pendingIntent2);
```

Items are created, added to the widget, it looks great, BUT listeners are not working the way I want - only the first listener for the first button works, others doesn't. I suppose its because I register setOnClickPendingIntent for both buttons with same id (R.id.singleLine) - but the biggest problem is, that i cant set id of button when its inside remoteview...

Is there some way to do thing like this? Thx a lot

EDIT: This is my layout item, i'm trying to generate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/singleLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTime"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fontNewsCompact" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCurrency"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fontNewsExtraCompact" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the action must be different for each intent, if you don't change it it will only take the first  (or the last, depending on your flags).

What I have done in similar situations is give an additional unique identifier to the action such as:

```
intent1.setAction(Constants.ACTION_PRESSED_ITEM + "-1");
...
intent2.setAction(Constants.ACTION_PRESSED_ITEM + "-2");
```

Then on your ForexWidget class use something as:

```
if (intent.getAction().startsWith(Constants.ACTION_PRESSED_ITEM) {

    // your logic here
}
```

Also, to add a pending intent to objects with the same Id, you should go to the deepest scope you can so that you enclose only one item with that Id. That way the intents should be added as follows:

```
currentItem1.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.singleLine, pendingIntent1)
...
currentItem2.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.singleLine, pendingIntent2)
```

this way you are on the scope of your list item layout

Comment: well, for me it doesnt work - of course, because Im setting onClickPendingIntent 2x for the same id as u can see. The question of a day is, how to avoid this...For more info I've updated my first post and added the layout I'm trying to generate (with id singleLine)

Comment: I know you are using the same Id, but it must be different. If you are using that Id to make some logic on your ForexWidget class, then use action.startsWith(Constants.Action_PRESSED_ITEM) instead of an equality.

Comment: I understand u absolutely, but its not the main problem. Problem is, that I'm doing this `updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.singleLine, pendingIntent1)` and this `updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.singleLine, pendingIntent2)` so actually i'm registering 2 onclick intents for one item `R.id.singleLine` - also I've 2 instances. But how to register it correctly? Because something like this `updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(currentItem1.getLayoutId(), pendingIntent1)` and this `updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(currentItem2.getLayoutId(), pendingIntent2)` of course doesnt work..

Comment: Ahhh, ok. Well what you can do is use 
`currentItem1.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.singleLine, pendingIntent1)` and this
`currentItem2.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.singleLine, pendingIntent2)`, this way you are on the scope of your list item layout